# Why std::unique_lock changes std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pointers, locking

I've something strange happening here, at least for me it is strange...

I've a thread-function with ...

```
void run(std::mutex &mtx, std::condition_variable &cv)
{
    std::unique_ptr<float[]> shiftbuf(new float[SHIFTBUF_SIZE]);
    float *const shiftbuf_p = shiftbuf.get();

    for (;;)
    {
        *(shiftbuf_p + SHIFTBUF_SIZE - 1) = 100.f;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        cv.notify_all();
    }
}
```

In main something like ...

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::thread th(run, std::ref(mtx), std::ref(cv));

std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

cv.wait(lck);
```

When I debug the code and watch `shiftbuf_p` the **address changes** on `lck`?!

```
Thread 18 "..." hit Hardware watchpoint 4: shiftbuf_p

Old value = (float * const) 0x7fffd8000b10
New value = (float * const) 0x7fffd8000b01
run (mtx=..., cv_second=..., amplitude_data=..., tm=...)
    at ....cpp:132
132             std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Thread 18 "..." hit Hardware watchpoint 4: shiftbuf_p

Old value = (float * const) 0x7fffd8000b01
New value = (float * const) 0x7fffd8000001
run (mtx=..., cv_second=..., amplitude_data=..., tm=...)
    at ....cpp:132
132             std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Thread 18 "..." hit Hardware watchpoint 5: shiftbuf_p

Old value = (float * const) 0x7fffd8000001
New value = (float * const) 0x7fff00000001
run (mtx=..., cv_second=..., amplitude_data=..., tm=...)
    at ....cpp:132
132             std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Thread 18 "..." received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

And it **never changes back** to the correct origin address.
When `run()` continues `shiftbuf_p` points to wrong address.

Why does the address change? It is a **const pointer**. The unique_ptr scope is top in the child-thread. The wait call is in main thread.

But also `shiftbuf.get()` returns `nullptr`. Like unique_ptr `shiftbuf` went out of scope, but this shouldn't occur with this code, shouldn't it?

Can you explain what is happening?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example which at least compiles

Comment: Is optimization enabled?

Comment: Probably the `shiftbuf_p` variable is optimized out as unused, and the space is reused for `lck`.

Comment: `std::condition_variable cv; cv.wait(lck);` that doesn't make sense, you are waiting on a locally created cv and your thread is notifying some other cv (you didn't show where the other one comes from)

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<float> shiftbuf(new float[SHIFTBUF_SIZE]);`

is wrong, the specialized `unique_ptr` for arrays needs to be used here.

`std::unique_ptr<float[]> shiftbuf(new float[SHIFTBUF_SIZE]);`

Comment: @BenVoigt I've changed it, but doesn't change anything. I think this might be only a problem if destructor is called.

Comment: @Markus: And for a primitive type like `float` it quite possibly wouldn't be a problem ever.  Still best to follow the contract.  So it's a comment not an answer.

Comment: @numzero It was -g -O2 but now -g -O0 and no change.

Comment: I've same behavior with malloc-ptr. Can't anybody tell me when/why the `float *const shiftbuf_p` changes the address? Why is this possible with `*const`?

Comment: Interesting. Is the mutex still alive when that happens? Provide a minimal `main` which causes this to happen, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think I've found my problem.
There was another data array on the stack and this one has been used to write over its bounds, because its index was totally out of control.
And so the `shiftbuf_p` address might got changed.
Hard to find... No -fstack-protector or valgrind detected the cause.

Comment: `-fstack-protector` can only protect from stack *frame* overflow (i.e. when the corruption goes behind *all* local variables), and only on return. Not sure of `valgrind`, but it is aimed at heap allocations AFAIK.